# Analysing messages residing in a queue RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, message

I have several Java Clients sending messages to a queue using RabbitMQ default exchange.

I want to be able to analyse the messages inside of the queue (if they are not consumed obviously), identify the sender of the message and if a Client is sending too many messages then bind a special queue so that this client sends messages to that queue .

I am new with RabbitMQ so What I would like to know is :

- Is it possible to append a client ID as a header in RabbitMQ?
- How to create a special queue for clients with much workload?
- Is it possible to analyse messages residing in a queue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to append a client ID as a header in RabbitMQ?

you can use the headers field on `BasicProperties`

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("myclientid",  22222);

channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey,
             new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
               .headers(headers)
               .build()),
               messageBodyBytes);
```

> How to create a special queue for clients with much workload?

There are no "special" queues, you can add more consumers to the same queue, in case you have an high workload. See 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

> Is it possible to analyse messages residing in a queue?

You can use the API `basic_get` without ACK the message, in this way you can read a messages without remove them from the queue

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I just want need one more consumer for this specific client